# First occurrence of a number in python list

Tags: python

I have a long list which consist of two fixed possible numbers (0 and 1). e.g:

```
 l = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

I don't know  which number occurs first in the list but I am sure that if 0
is occurring first in the list then it will occur consecutively followed by 1, same case for 1.

I am performing some kind of action on the basis of these number conditions (0,1) but also I need to show a message before the first occurrence of 0 and 1.

First occurrence of first number (in this case 0), I have managed like this.

```
if l[0] == 0:
   print ('first occurrence of 0')
elif l[0] == 1:
   print ('first occurrence of 1')
```

I am not sure how to point out first occurrence of 1 during execution of this list.

For this example list I need result like this.

```
 msg before first occurrence of 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 msg before first occurrence of 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: Keep a flag variable(`one_seen`) set to `False` until you've not seen the first 1, set it to `True` once you've seen a 1.

Comment: `list.index` can help you find the first occurrence of an item. But if you are printing items in a loop, I would use Ashwini's suggestion.

Comment: It's not clear what is your question. Do you want to detect the first `0` and the first `1` in the list, or is this something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that works for more than just 0 and 1 can be based to a `set` containing the elements we encountered so far:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
s = set()
for x in l:
    if x not in s:
        print("first occurrence of %s" % x)
        s.add(x)
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
first occurrence of 0
0
0
0
0
0
first occurrence of 1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Bah, I accidentally hit enter and it saved before I could write the edit message. I thought your original wording was confusing in the negative since it sounded like maybe 0 and 1 was the only case where it didn't work. Reworded it to be positive. :)

Comment: No problem. I like it and I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 8):

Use `index` to find the first occurrence of an item in a `list`

```
>>> l = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
>>> l.index(0)
0
>>> l.index(1)
5
```

Comment: And you could use `l.index(1 - l[0])` to find the earliest element differing from the first, assuming the elements really are all 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using python Recursion as well which finds first occurrence of any given number in a list. You can modify for your requirement.

Here is the following code.

```
def firstIndex(a, x):
l = len(a)
if l == 0:
    return -1
if a[0] == x:
    return 0
sa = a[1:]
smlist_output = firstIndex(sa, x)
if smlist_output == -1:
    return -1
else:
    return smlist_output + 1



# Main
   from sys import setrecursionlimit
   setrecursionlimit(11000)
   n=int(input()) # Read the length of an list to read the list elements from the console
   arr=list(int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' ')) # Read list elements from the console
   x=int(input()) # read the number to be found in the list
   print(firstIndex(arr, x))
```

input1:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
4
```

Output1:

```
3
```

input2:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
9
```

Output2:

```
-1
```

The function returns index as -1 if your given number does not exists in the list.